# apache camel "Jetty vs Servlet" in web application

Tags: apache-camel

In our project we are planning to use apache camel for web request routing / orchestration.

Its basically a web project talking to several other internal web-services to prepare the final response to the requester.

Can someone suggest, what is the best/standard way to consume the web requests in a camel web application ?

I believe its possible in camel with several options :

- servlet-listenter + servlet component combination
- Jetty component
- spring web and xml (*we want to avoid any spring dependencies*)
- any other way ???

It would be really helpful if some has done this before and can guide.
Any pointers like pros and cons are also well appreciated.

Note: *As I mentioned above, we don't want to have any spring related dependencies in the project.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Jetty](http://camel.apache.org/jetty.html) is the simplest way to receive a request from some given URL.

```
from("jetty:http://localhost:{{port}}/myapp/myservice")
    .process() // do something with the Exchange
```

This is easy to get running however you may end up with some tricky routing rules to differentiate between GETs, POSTs and so on. IMHO multiple paths of execution in a camel route (ie with splits, choices etc) can/will become a trap for the unwary.

[Servlets](http://camel.apache.org/servlet.html) are trickier as you need to write the Servlet implementation and register it in the Servlet container (eg via web.xml) and the result is the same - you get a HTTP request as an exchange.

```
web.xml

<web-app>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>CamelServlet</servlet-name>
    <display-name>Camel Http Transport Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.camel.component.servlet.CamelHttpTransportServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>  
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CamelServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping> 
</web-app>

RouteBuilder
    from("servlet:///hello?matchOnUriPrefix=true").process(new Processor() {
        // do stuff
```

I dont think there's any advantage to this over the jetty component.

[Camel Rest DSL](http://camel.apache.org/rest-dsl.html) is my pick. It's a simple DSL for describing HTTP endpoints with nice REST semantics, it's clear what the routing rules are and it's relatively succinct. This only works with 2.14 onwards though..

```
       rest("/say")
            .get("/hello").to("direct:hello")
            .get("/bye").consumes("application/json").to("direct:bye")
            .post("/bye").to("mock:update");

        from("direct:hello")
            .transform().constant("Hello World");
        from("direct:bye")
            .transform().constant("Bye World");
```

Comment: In the Rest DSL or for that matter any non-servlet implementations, what is the suggested way to keep the camel context thread running all the time ?

Comment: It depends on how you start the camel context -there are heaps of options such as using the MainSupport class, in a spring container, osgi, in a War file and probably others. Redhat would say use Fuse/OSGi but that brings a large cognitive and app overhead for a simple app. Personally I think a jar with the camel MainSupport class is the way to go. If you need to run it on tomcat or something then look at this http://camel.apache.org/tutorial-on-using-camel-in-a-web-application.html (although given you want to avoid spring that may not be the best way to go)